# Copy and paste vertical cells into horizontal rows on another sheet at the end

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a vertical set of data from an input form, let's call it a survey. This survey asks for name, email, and age. The surveys get compiled into Sheet2 in one long list, let's say 100 responses, or 300 lines.

I want to be able to pivot this data, and therefore need to put it into a horizontal table that has NAME|EMAIL|AGE at the top, then fills in the responses below, starting a new row each time you hit the name, or every 4th cell repeating.

I have this, which takes the current page and transposes it, but I need to be able to run this macro to copy and paste from one sheet to another.

Here is the code I have if helpful:

```
Public Sub TransposeData()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 8

        .Cells(i, "A").Resize(8).Copy
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
        .Cells(NextRow, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Next i

    .Rows(NextRow + 1).Resize(LastRow - NextRow).Delete
    .Columns(1).Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Public Sub TransposeData()

    Const NUM As Long = 4
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range

    Set rngCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(NUM, 1)
    Set rngPaste = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    Do While Application.CountA(rngCopy) > 0

        rngCopy.Copy
        rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

        Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(NUM, 0)
        Set rngPaste = rngPaste.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop

End Sub
```